# Need help selecting child div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm having a tough time with something that I think is pretty simple. I hope you folks can help me.

I'm using a jquery plugin called [zoomtoo](https://github.com/sevagf/zoomtoo).

I need to have the plugin function (`zoomToo()`) applied on a child div (`modal-img-wrap`) inside its parent div (`modal`).

**The JS script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".modal").zoomToo({
            magnify: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

**The HTML code:**

```
<body>

    <div id="ex2" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-img-wrap">
            <img class="modal-img" src="homedrive.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you post the html code with the divs. And you show us which parent and which child.

Comment: And please provide a link to the web page of zoomtoo plugin.

Comment: Sorry about that. I knew that you needed the HTML. I just had a hard time getting it in the post but it is there now. Here is the link to the plugin I am using. https://github.com/thompsonemerson/zoomove

Comment: No problem ;-) It's good that it's all there now.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it isn't [this link](https://github.com/sevagf/zoomtoo)?

Comment: Yes it is that link....It seems that the plugin only works on the parent div. I have a styled div with css within this parent div that contains the image. I need the zoom function to work with this styled div call ".modal-img-wrap".

Comment: Is it possible to have the javascript select the "modal-img-wrap" div instead of the "modal" div. I need it to select the child div within the parent div.

Comment: Yes. Just write `$(".modal .modal-img-wrap").zoomToo({...});`.

Comment: Yes I tried that. I get the crosshairs with the pointer but the image does not zoom. It seems to want to work. Think I need to play around with the css styles.....?.... Thank you for all your help  aendeerei....!!!

Comment: Well, now it's up to you. Move the pointer to the left or right margin of the image. It should work.

Comment: I just reedited your question to be better formatted. You have more buttons on the upper side, from which you can choose to accept the edits, to reject them, or etc. In principle, other users can reedit your questions for different reasons. If you like the edits, accept them; if no, then don't. They serve to make this website better... Ok, I'm done now. Bye.

Comment: Thank you  aendeerei.... Your help is greatly appreciiated. I am new to this.... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example. Notice the attributes in the divs. And bind the `jquery.zoomtoo.min.js` script, because it's minified, e.g. smaller. If you already have a css class on the image containing div (`modal-img-wrap`), then you can also directly reference it inside js. So, instead of `.modal .modal-img-wrap` you can write `.modal-img-wrap` in js script.

Good luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="dist/jquery.zoomtoo.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $(".modal-img-wrap").zoomToo({
                    magnify: 1
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="ex2" class="modal"><!-- Not this div -->
            <div class="modal-img-wrap" data-src="homedrive_big.jpg"><!-- I need this div selected by the plugin. -->
                <img class="modal-img" src="homedrive_normal.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH...!. I think this will work and I truly appreciate your time with this....

Comment: @MichaelFitzgerald You are very welcome. Keep in mind for the future: when an answer solves your problem, then you should mark it as accepted (with the "check mark" on the left side of the answer). And if you think an answer deserves an up- or a down-vote, then use the arrows on the left side of the answer. This way, the other users will benefit from the solution too. But please don't mark my answer as accepted though. I just wrote you this comment, so that you know how to proceed in the future. Bye and have fun with that cool tool. I think I'll use it in my projects too ;-)

Comment: @MichaelFitzgerald With pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, you can select the div by name $( "#MyDiv" ).  Set the name property of the div.

$(function() {

```
        $("#MyDiv").zoomToo({
            magnify: 1
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I am placing this zoom plugin inside a modal.... I have a div within this modal with my responsive css styles. I need the zoom function to work within the "modal-img-wrap" div and not the modal div which is the "modal" div.